# How to override content css property to not to use it on IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, font-awesome

I'm using font-awesome on my application and when I have ajax requests, I call a hidden `<div>` that displays a font-awesome icon:

```
<div id="loading" style="z-index:9999; margin-left:45%; display:none;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
```

It works just the way I want, but on **IE8**, font-awesome doesn't support the spin functionality, so, I had the following idea:

I'll use the **ie.css** (an specific css file I have that applies css changes only to IE), and I'm going to replace the class `.fa-spinner:before` to replace the content for a `background-image` with a `gif` icon.

```
.fa-spinner:before{
    background-image: url("../image/ajax-loader.gif");
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    content: "";
    content: none;
}
```

The gif icon is being displayed, but it seems that that static fa-spin icon was not removed (I tried to override it by using the `content:""` and `content: none` to try to make it remove the icon, and displays only the gif image).

Somehow the font-awesome icon is still there, when it shouldn't. The problem is that I'm not succeeding to replace the content css property.

Comment: Note that the `content: ''` hack is only meant for non-IE browsers so you don't need that extra declaration - `content: none` should suffice (at least, in situations where `content: none` should work anyway, I know it doesn't work for you right now).

Comment: yeah.. it didn't work.. thanks for the explanation.. I already removed it. I'll apply the idea @anstosa provided. it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the gif background to `#loading` in `ie.css` and simply hide the FontAwesome spinner with

```
#loading i {
    display: none;
}
```

This approach will likely be more reliable than trying to surgically override a single property from FontAwesome.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! it worked like a charm! I agree with you it is better than applying changes to fontawesome.